# Unable to create user -Django.conrib.auth

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, admin

I am Trying to create a Login system using Django inbuilt django.contrib.auth.models.user
i am not getting any error in the code all files are check, but when i am trying the save the user in the database i can't see the user which i created in the django admin panel
i am getting all the details through html form and exxtracting that values in views.py, but even after migrations

**signup.html**

```
 <form method="POST" action="home/">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
    </form>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.

    def signup(request):
        if request.method=='POST':
            username=request.POST.get('username')
            email=request.POST.get('email')
            password=request.POST.get('password')
            confirm_password=request.POST.get('confirm_password')
            the_user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
            the_user.save()
        return render(request,'signup.html')
    
    def home(request):
        return HttpResponse('Login Successfull')
```

**This Is Django Admin Panel**

[image: Here i am unable to save my created user]

Comment: You are posting data to `home` not to `signup`. So you get just `return HttpResponse('Login Successfull')` and the user does not get created.